# Difference between using wpa_supplicant and /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking

I've used the wpa_supplicant and changed the interface to use this and I can get the pi to connect to the network.

```
network {
    ssid="YOUR_NETWORK_NAME"
    psk="YOUR_NETWORK_PASSWORD"
}
```

I can also just use interfaces with

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
      wpa-ssid "network"
      wpa-psk "password"
```

and I get it to connect to wifi as well.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raspbian uses `dhcpcd` to manage networks. Despite the name this does more than allocate addresses; it can actively switch between networks and interfaces, and repair broken connections. `/etc/network/interfaces` uses `wpasupplicant` to provide details of known wireless networks (and other optional settings). (`dhcpcd` can directly call `wpasupplicant`, but Raspbian Jessie omitted the hook to do this, although this is included in Stretch and Buster.)

See:-
[How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

`etc/network/interfaces` is used by used by ifup and ifdown.

It can be used to provide a simple static setup, which can be managed manually. The default works with `dhcpcd` and `wpasupplicant`.

One disadvantage of putting wireless settings in interfaces (apart from lack of flexibility) is that any user can read password.

Comment: *One disadvantage of putting wireless settings in interfaces (apart from lack of flexibility) is that any user can read password.*

That's actually wrong, you can use `wpa_supplicant ssid password` and use the generated password in the interface by setting it with `wpa-psk`.

Comment: @eXa you made a typo? maybe `wpa_passphrase`?

Comment: @schemacs Nope https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is that:

- `/etc/network/interfaces` file refer to all interfaces of the network
- where `wpa_supplicant` is focused on wireless communication.

Using interface file, you can control the interface.

`wpa_supplicant`, you can control the setting to connect to the wireless hub.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that wpasupplicant does the WPA security and interfaces does the WiFi transport after the secure connection is made.